# Stripe IOS SDK Not Working After 3DS2 Update

Tags: ios, sdk, payment

I have downloaded the Stripe iOS SDK Example Automatic Confirmation Flow model. I have integrated Stripe successfully into my iOS app and have had to revert to this example for reference as when my user now gets to the point of checkout, once a payment intent is created, the SDK can no longer handle 3DS2.

This is the output I am getting when I use a test card that requires 3D authentication. I haven't changed any code besides the backend url and publishable key in the stripe sdk https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios

```
2019-07-22 19:05:29.082023+0100 Standard Integration[7508:2891014] -[TVg isChallengeMandated]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281111420
2019-07-22 19:05:29.082288+0100 Standard Integration[7508:2891014] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TVg isChallengeMandated]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281111420'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x20b9eb3a8 0x20abefd00 0x20b9039f8 0x20b9f0d54 0x20b9f2b50 0x102696aa4 0x1026800dc 0x102715dec 0x1034471fc 0x10344877c 0x103456158 0x20b97b024 0x20b975cd4 0x20b975254 0x20dbb4d8c 0x23979a850 0x10221c524 0x20b430fd8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: According to this old issue the problem might be in your backend response format https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/826

Comment: Thanks Evgenii, unfortunately im not sure thats the issue as the example SDK uses Stripe’s example backend server?

Comment: Sorry @halfer, new round here !! Will refrain from doing that again 

Comment: You said you've  changed backend url. I'm good with Stripe integrations, but don't have experience with iOS native development, so I'm not sure how to debug it